# IserviceCollection does not contain defination of "AddDefaultIdentity"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

`AddDefaultIdentity` throwing error

```
'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDefaultIdentity' and 

no accessible extension method 'AddDefaultIdentity' accepting a first argument 

of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

`WebApiDotNet.AddDefaultIdentity` does not exist in `IServiceCollection`

[image: Error]

Comment: What's your Identity configuration code in Startup.cs?

Answer (score 8):

> 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddDefaultIdentity' and no accessible extension method 'AddDefaultIdentity' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I reproduced the issue when I installed `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` package higher than version 3.0 in a 3.0 project.  **Note:** `AddDefaultIdentity` extension method is used to add the default UI service for Razor Pages and MVC.

You could use `AddIdentity` instead of `AddDefaultIdentity` like below:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

If you want to use `AddDefaultIdentity`, you should update the version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI` to 3.0.

For the difference between AddDefaultIdentity and AddIdentity , refer to https://medium.com/@xsoheilalizadeh/asp-net-core-identity-deep-dive-stores-e0e54291b51d